# HAXM max RAM size = 0 MB after -m command

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I am trying to run two emulators (Different devices ) on Android Studio.
When I first ran the second, I had this error:

```
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
```

So I lowered the devices' RAM  from 1024 MB to 512 MB, but the error remained the same.
So I tried to increase HAXM max RAM to 1024 MB by running this command:

`silent_install.bat -m 1024` --- > `Intel HAXM updated successfully!`

After that, I ran the emulator and the error is the same, except now

`emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 0 MB`

How come? I meant to increase the HAXM max RAM.
How do I increase it back and run two emulators simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

AVD setting generally should be equal to or LOWER than the HAXM limit - which should be for all AVDs you are running. What OS?

Comment: Oh, I am using windows 10

Comment: If you receive an "exceeds memory limit" while launching an AVD it is because the AVD's RAM Memory Option exceeds the Intel HAXM Memory Reservation set during install. You can either increase the HAXM Memory Reservation or decrease the AVD's RAM
Memory Option.  Probably best to reinstall haxm (~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager \intelhamx_android.exe.) and try setting HAXM RAM to 1024MB and AVD RAM to 768MB.